# Could this be a Bad CV shaft or boot?

Tags: honda, drive-shaft

[image]

I hear a tic-tic crumpling sound while the steering is turned/locked and the vehicle moves forward or backward using power. In neutral these sounds are not present.

Comment: Since I cannot see the image (at work), the boot is *very easy* to diagnose: is it split and spewing grease? If so, it's bad. Simple as that. If you are actually asking if it's "just" the boot, or something more, you may want to clarify that in your question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's spewing greese on the boot holder. But how can I diagnose a failing or failed CV shaft?

Comment: If it's spewing grease, it's loosing vital lubrication.  It's busticated.  Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this sound is a heavier and regular knocking type sound as you're moving forwards or backwards whilst applying a little throttle on full steering lock, it indicates a failing CV joint.

Comment: CV joints are a substantial unit however if old or improperly maintained e.g.running with split boots for a while then off-roading certainly won't help with their longevity as the torsional loads and stresses through the bearings are higher. once the bearings and surfaces have started to wear though the CV won't recover and off could bring on failure.

Comment: They can of course just start knocking with age and mileage too. I've replaced CV units on vehicles only a few years old. Admittedly these are usually vehicles with over 50k or more on the clock.

Comment: If its already knocking then no not really, taking it apart then re-packing with grease etc may only suppress the knock slightly for a while. The knock actually originates from possibly already oval bearings rolling on worn cup slides. You would be far better getting a reconditioned CV joint, or even perhaps try a second hand one, however sometimes with second hand stuff you can end up with parts that are worse than the parts you're using now, so reconditioned or new is best way really.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean regarding a none spinning CV joint. Whatever that is if it's different to the original manufacturers design I would not advise it at all.